# SQL compare 2 columns and find a duplicate value in 2nd Column with specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have the following set up

```
CREATE TABLE #TestEmailTable
(
    companyId INT,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    emailAddress VARCHAR(255)
)

 INSERT #TestEmailTable VALUES 
 (570599,'emailAddress@bob.com','emailAddress@bob.com'),
 (570589,'hello@bob.com','goodbye@gmail.com'),
 (109350,'dupedAddress@bob2.com','homeAddress@bob2.com'),
 (109350,'anotherAddress@bob4.com','dupedAddress@bob2.com');
```

I am trying to find the row/rows of data where the `companyID` is the same and there is a duplicated value in the `emailaddress` column when comparing to the username column of a different user. So in this example the first row of data would not count as a duplicate. But row 3 and 4 would count as a duplicate because the `companyId` is the same and username `dupedAddress@bob2.com` in the `username` column in row 3 is the same as the `dupedAddress@bob2.com` in the `emailAddress` column in row 4.

Below is an attempt I made but it does not work

```
select a.*,b.hasADuplicate
from #TestEmailTable a
inner join (
    select companyId,username ,count(*) hasADuplicate
    from #TestEmailTable 
    group by companyId,username
) b on b.companyId = a.companyId and b.username = a.emailAddress
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve

| companyId | username | emailAddress | hasADuplicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 109350 | dupedAddress@bob2.com | homeAddress@bob2.com | 1 |

Comment: why not just join table on itself where a.username = b.email but a.username !=b.username

Comment: @Paul, what result would you expect if the test data contained the row `(570599, 'brave@knight.net', 'emailAddress@bob.com')`?

Comment: Thanks for the help earlier today! @AndreiOdegov I would expect to see another row with 570599 | emailAddress@bob.com | emailAddress@bob.com | 1

Comment: @siggemannen yes this makes sense and when it's written like that it's easier to comprehend and compose

Comment: @Paul, your response to my comment made your problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to solve the problem by using the [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) logical operator and surrogate row identifiers to avoid comparing rows with themselves.

```
with
  T as (
    select
      row_number() over(partition by companyId
                        order by (select null)) as rowid,
      *
    from #TestEmailTable
  )
select
  companyid, username, emailAddress
from T
where exists(
        select *
        from T as b
        where b.companyId = T.companyId and
              b.emailAddress = T.username and
              b.rowid != T.rowid
      );
```

If you ignore the warning not to use undocumented features, you can use the pseudo-column `%%physloc%%` as a row identifier.

```
select
  companyid, username, emailAddress
from #TestEmailTable as a
where exists(
        select *
        from #TestEmailTable as b
        where b.companyId = a.companyId and
              b.emailAddress = a.username and
              b.%%physloc%% != a.%%physloc%%
      );
```

If the columns `companyId` and `emailAddress` are a composite unique key, then the query may be the following:

```
select
  companyid, username, emailAddress
from #TestEmailTable as a
where exists(
        select *
        from #TestEmailTable as b
        where b.companyId = a.companyId and
              b.username != a.username and
              b.emailAddress = a.username
      );
```

All three queries give the same result.

```
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| companyid |       username        |     emailAddress     |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|    109350 | dupedAddress@bob2.com | homeAddress@bob2.com |
+-----------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Try it in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q7YTp9ae).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.companyId, a.username, a.emailAddress, COUNT(*) AS hasADuplicate
FROM #TestEmailTable a
JOIN #TestEmailTable b ON a.companyId = b.companyId
                      AND a.username = b.emailAddress
                      AND a.username <> a.emailAddress
GROUP BY a.companyId, a.username, a.emailAddress
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

The above query joins the table with itself based on the `companyId` and checks for rows where the `emailAddress` in one row matches the `username` in another row with the same `companyId`. The `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` ensures that only rows with duplicates are included in the result.

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Something to bear in mind - the example answer above doesn't work with absolute duplicates. I see exceptions where 1, a@a.com, a@a.com duplicated twice wouldn't report. Is this possible within your data?

Are you interested in cases where the username is duplicated or the email is duplicated within their respective columns too, or ONLY cases where the duplication occurs cross-column?

If you're after a more granular level of control, you can effectively create an inline recordnumber using row_number, as follows. This approach can be scaled up across multiple columns and effectively counts the number of records the data item features in.

```
with alldata as
(
below
   select 
      companyid, username, emailaddress, 
      row_number() over (order by companyid, username, emailaddress) 'record' 
   from #testemailtable
)
select email, count(distinct record) 'records'
from 
(
   select username 'email', record
   from sourcedata
   union 
   select emailaddress, record
   from sourcedata
) x
group by email 
having count(distinct record) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Ephasius I'm ONLY interested cases where the duplication occurs cross-column?